What are other methods to find the distance from point P(x0,y0) to the line determined by points A(x1,y1) and B(x2,y2)?
What are other methods to find the distance from point P(x0,y0) to the line determined by points A(x1,y1) and B(x2,y2)?

Method one:
line = InfiniteLine[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}];
d = RegionDistance[line, {x0, y0}]

for example:
line = InfiniteLine[{{2, 3}, {4, 5}}];
d = RegionDistance[line, {0, 0}]

1/Sqrt[2]


Methpd two:
pointToLineDistance[{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}] := 
 Module[{a, b, c}, a = y2 - y1;
  b = x1 - x2;
  c = x2*y1 - x1*y2;
  Abs[a*x0 + b*y0 + c]/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]]
d = pointToLineDistance[{x0, y0}, {x1, y1}, {x2, y2}]

for example:
pointToLineDistance[{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}] := 
 Module[{a, b, c}, a = y2 - y1;
  b = x1 - x2;
  c = x2*y1 - x1*y2;
  Abs[a*x0 + b*y0 + c]/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]]
d = pointToLineDistance[{0, 0}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}]

1/Sqrt[2]

Method three:
unitNormalVector[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}] := 
  Normalize[{-((y2 - y1)), (x2 - x1)}];
lineVector[{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}] := {x1 - x0, y1 - y0};

pointToLineDistance[{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}] := 
 Module[{uV, lV}, uV = unitNormalVector[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}];
  lV = lineVector[{x0, y0}, {x1, y1}];
  Abs[uV . lV]]
```


Why do you need other methods?

You can just get WL to spit out the abstract formula once and then turn that into a function: FullSimplify @ RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[Array[y, {2, 2}]], Array[x, 2]].

Here is an approach. f produces point of intersection with line and distance, vis produces a visualization:
f[a_, b_, p_] := Module[{v = a - b, n, i},
   n = {1, -1} v[[{2, 1}]];
   i = v  s + b /. Solve[ v  s + b == n  t + p , {s, t}][[1]];
   {i, Norm[i - p]}
   ];
vis[a_, b_, p_] := 
 Module[{u, v}, {u, v} = f[a, b, p]; 
  Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Blue, InfiniteLine[{a, b}], 
    Point[{a, b}], Red, Point[{u, p}], Black, Line[{u, p}], 
    Text[v, (u + p)/2, {-1, -1}]}, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]]

Some examples:
a = {2, 3};
b = {4, 5};
p = {0, 0};
Row[{vis[a, b, p],
  vis[{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 2}],
  vis[{2, 2}, {4, 4}, {1, 5}]}]


